# Why does a column of table has same values?

Tags: mysql

I'm inserting into a table using php where the values are taken from the user. What's happening is the contact column is getting the same value even if user gave different values.
Here's the snapshot of what I mean to say :[same vaue in each row of contact column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIwG4.png)

My php does this

```
    $cntct=$_POST['num'];
    $gen=$_POST['sex'];
    $addrs=$_POST['addr'];
    $sql="INSERT into users(contact,gender,address) VALUES('$cntct','$gen','$addrs')";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql)or die("Invalid query ".mysqli_error($db));
```

Comment: Please show us some code.  To ask the obvious question, are you sure your UI is actually sending across each new contact?

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: Your PHP code does not seem to explain your observations.  I'd check the code maing the POST to your script.  Make sure it isn't caching an old contact.

Comment: It's a registration form... all other data are inserted into the table as the user input. I've taken all the data into session variables after POST and updating them on each registration.

Comment: What is the example input for the "contact" value on your registration page and what is the data type of your "contact" column in your database? It looks like it's `INT` and you run unintentionally in a integer overflow while saving the new row.

Comment: Okay so how do I rectify it? @Progman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of data type `INT` in column contact. `INT` can only contain values between -2147483648 and 2147483647. So you have to use a `BIGINT` and it is always 8 bytes and can store -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

Comment: I do have contact validation. If its of concern?

Comment: You have to change the data type in mysql not in your code and validate the number within php.

Comment: Sorry I can't. It says I need to have 15 reputation!